# Is it possible to specify different default browser for different website?

Tags: windows, browser, browsing

I use Firefox for normal browsing (so it is my default browser), but I am also working with some websites that only works in IE. If I click a hyperlink (like link in the e-mail, document, chat client, etc.) it will always use my default browser. So for IE-only websites, I have to start IE, and copy paste the link (which is much less convenient than just clicking the link, especially because IE load time is very slow).

Is it possible to have different default browsers for some websites? For example, if I click a hyperlink for websites with domain microsoft.com, Windows will open it using IE instead of my default browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the [IE Tab +](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-plus/?src=ss) extension for firefox, using the **Site filter** setting. There is a default rule that will use the IE engine for every site matching `http://*update.microsoft.com/*`, that you can easily modify to `http://*microsoft.com/*` to open every site from the microsoft domain within the IE engine.